# login with Facebook Laravel problem socialite

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite

I am creating a Laravel app and I want to include login with facebook, but I have this error:

Argument 1 passed to Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteManager::formatRedirectUrl() must be of the type array, null given, called in

If someone can help me I would be so thankful.

-The repo is in github: https://github.com/victorvidalv/laravel

Comment: did you try clearing config?

php artisan config:clear

Comment: Any more information on where in your code is happening or more of the stack trace would help pinpoint what may be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended by Laravel to use their default package for socialite.

Here is the link to the github repo, https://github.com/laravel/socialite.

Here is the documentation for the package https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/socialite

Follow the documentation and you will be successful.